# How to properly format nested try/catch blocks inside a function that returns a server response

Tags: javascript, typescript, async-await

I have a function that is called that must return a response to a server. Inside this function are two `await` function calls that are nested. To track error handling, I added `try/catch` blocks. Is there a way to avoid having nested try catch blocks to track all cases where the function might fail so I can send back an error server response?

Here's my function, it queries for a user's unique device id's and sends a push notification to each one. If a token becomes invalid, then I delete it from my database:

```
function findUserDevices(uid: string, message) {
    collectionData(fb.firestore().collection('devices').where('userId', '==', uid)).pipe(
        filter((userDevices) => userDevices && userDevices.length > 0),
        take(1)
    ).subscribe( async (devices: any) => {
        var userDeviceTokens: string[] = devices.map((device: any) => device.token);
        if (userDeviceTokens !== undefined && userDeviceTokens.length != 0) {
            try {
                message['tokens'] = userDeviceTokens;
                const pushResponse = await admin.messsaging().sendMulticast(message);
                if (pushResponse.failureCount > 0) {
                    const failedTokens = [];
                    pushResponse.responses.forEach((resp, idx) => {
                        if (!resp.success) {
                            failedTokens.push(userDeviceTokens[idx]);
                        }
                    });
                    failedTokens.forEach( async (token) => {
                        var tokenInstanceID = token.split(':')[0];
                        try {
                            await deleteOldToken(tokenInstanceID);
                            console.log(`Token ${tokenInstanceID} deleted`)
                        } catch {
                            return res.status(500).send("err");
                        }
                    })
                    return res.status(200).send("ok");
                } else {
                    return res.status(200).send("ok");
                }
            } catch {
                return res.status(500).send("err");
            }
        } else {
            return res.status(200).send("ok");
        }
    })
}
```

It just feels a bit excessive with all the `returns` I must have. Where can I improve?

**EDIT, broke apart code into three blocks to prevent arrow coding**

```
function findUserDevices(uid: string, message) {
        collectionData(fb.firestore().collection('devices').where('userId', '==', uid)).pipe(
            filter((userDevices) => userDevices && userDevices.length > 0),
            take(1)
        ).subscribe(async (devices: any) => {
            var userDeviceTokens: string[] = devices.map((device: any) => device.token);
            if (userDeviceTokens !== undefined && userDeviceTokens.length != 0) {
                try {
                    message['tokens'] = userDeviceTokens;
                    const response = await admin.messaging().sendMulticast(message);
                    const oldTokensArray = checkOldTokens(response, userDeviceTokens);
                    if (oldTokensArray.length > 0) {
                        await deleteOldTokens(oldTokensArray);
                        return res.status(200).send("ok");
                    } else {
                        return res.status(200).send("ok");
                    }
                } catch (err) {
                    return res.status(500).send(err);
                }
            } else {
                return res.status(200).send("ok");
            }
        })
    }

function checkOldTokens(response, userDeviceTokens) {
    if (response.failureCount > 0) {
        const failedTokens = [];
        response.responses.forEach((resp, idx) => {
            if (!resp.success) {
                failedTokens.push(userDeviceTokens[idx]);
            }
        });
        return failedTokens;
    } else {
        return [];
    }
}

async function deleteOldTokens(tokenArray) {
    for (const token of tokenArray) {
        await fb.firestore().collection('devices').doc(token).delete();
    }
}
```

Comment: Honestly, I’d start by refactoring this whole function. This level of nested blocks (`if`/`else`, `try`/`catch`, etc.) creates what is called “arrow code” (because it creates a point to the right side of your screen). It needs to be broken down into multiple functions or otherwise “flattened.” In any case, you don’t seem to need two `try`/`catch` blocks; the inner one is entirely redundant.

Comment: For how to tackle this, see https://blog.codinghorror.com/flattening-arrow-code/

Comment: @EdCottrell thanks for the suggestions so far Ed, I went ahead and tried to refactor my code to make it less arrow like, any thoughts on improvement for here? I think I have a better understanding of how to utilize async/await now. Just want to make sure I'm doing things the right way of course :)